# Reducing the number of faces on a basic text mesh

Tags: mesh, faces, edges

I want to create a text animation in blender. I'm trying to reduce the number of faces in my mesh. I'm having a lot of trouble adding faces to certain letters after I have gotten rid of some of the edges. For example, when I try to fill the letter "A" the entire letter including the negative space is filled.  I've tried ripping and separating the match but I haven't had much success.  I'm trying to mimic a YouTube tutorial but I'll never get to the end if I can't get the mesh straight.

I've included a screenshot of my project and a link to the video. My knowledge of edges vertices and faces or lack thereof is probably was giving me trouble.

I appreciate any assistance that you can give me
[image: BLENDER WORK SPACE]

[SAMPLE TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxDOhxjdFOs)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you try to delete too many edges on this kind of shape with a hole, Blender won't be able to understand what he's supposed to fill and what is supposed to be a hole. So keep the necessary edges. For example here are a try with an O with two different topologies:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that I need to create two separate meshes to make one letter "O"? I am relatively new at this so you may have to dumb it down. Thank you.

Comment: no I mean you need to keep some edges so that Blender understand what is supposed to be filled and what is supposed to be a hole. In the first solution I kept only one edge and it doesn't work because it doesn't understand that there is a hole

Comment: I tried to recreate when you did, but failed. How did you create the 2 vertical edges. I used the knife tool and  ended up cutting the entire object including the doughnut hole in half.  I put one circular mesh inside a second mesh.